# Proof by contradictions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Theorem: For all $a,b,c$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ if $a$ does not divide $b-c$, then $a$ does not divide $b$ or $a$ does not divide $c$.
Prove by contradiction

I know the first step is to flip the theorem to "there exists $a,b,c$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a$ does not divide $b-c$ and $a$ divides $b$ and $a$ divides $c$" but I am lost as to how to continue the proof.

Comment: what does $a$ divides $b$ mean?

Comment: that a is not zero and a is a factor of b

Comment: @MichalMosio Another way to write that $a$ is a factor of $b$ is to write that $b=ak_1$ for some $k_1 \in \Bbb Z$.  Now with this in mind what do you know about $c$?  What can you conclude about $b-c$?

Comment: @RobertShore we know the same information about c because of a|c

Comment: @MichalMosio Please write out precisely what you mean by "we know the same information."

Comment: $a$ is a factor of $c$ because $a$|$c$, therefore, $c$=$a$$k$ for some $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. We can also conclude $a$ is a factor of $b$ and $c$ when we do $b$-$c$ the new number will remain a factor of $a$. Therefore, $a$|$b$-$c$. Which would be the contradiction that we are looking for. Proving the original theorem true.

Comment: Haha, you've just already found the contradiction. Compare the negated statement (in your post) with what you just said (a| b-c). P.S. The title ought to be in the singular.

Comment: Thank you guys so much. I think I was just struggling with the technical terms for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"There exists a,b,c in Z such that a does not divide b−c and a divides b and a divides c"

That means we can write:

b = aq (q and q' are quotients)

c = aq'

so b-c can be written as

aq - aq'

a(q - q')

aQ (Q = q-q')

which Q is a quotient so a divides b-c, which is a contradiction.

To conclude, if a does not divide b−c, then a does not divide b or a does not divide c.